# Is there a way to easily resize a flash project?

Tags: flash, actionscript, resize, size, scale

I need to resize a flash project (or a swf, doesn't matter. whatever works best). But the only down-fall is I need to do it FAST, so are there any efficient ways I could "scale" the application?

Comment: Are you wanting to scale relative to the project window (eg everything gets scaled down) or keep the content dimensions and just make the bounding box bigger/smaller?

Comment: I need to scale everything down. The current size of the project is 1212 x 806 and I need it to scale to 1000 x 665.

Comment: Why won't just setting the stage size (or size of the swf in the browser) to 1000x665 work? Just trying to get a handle on what diff probs might be.

Answer (score 0):

Well flash is quite good in scaling, even bitmaps if they have their smoothing property set to true. If you load a swf inside another swf with your new width and height and then scale it by setting the width and height properties it should work just fine.